# Is there any way to set different colors of label base on the range of value in QValueAxis?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtcharts, qchart

I'm trying to plot a chart with axis labels of different colors for positive and negative values, the effect is shown in the image below. Is there any way to achieve it? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that with basic QValueAxis, but you could customize the appearance of custom ticks using QCategoryAxis, you only need to explicitly set the tick range.

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed a workaround, and I'll try it in some charts with fixed axes. But it is so troublesome for axes with dynamic range.

Comment: You need to rebuild the axis labels whenever the range changes. Just connect to the related signals of QValueAxis.